# Bundle vindo nulo

Tags: android

Estou tentando passar por parâmetros um valor de uma tela para outra, porém na outra chega nulo, vejam:

Tela 1:

```
Intent telaWeb = new Intent(SegmentoView.this, ViewWeb.class);
Bundle bundleParametro = new Bundle();
telaWeb.putExtras(bundleParametro);
bundleParametro.putString("link", urlStr);
startActivity(telaWeb);
```

Tela 2:

```
Intent dadosRecebidos = getIntent();
if(dadosRecebidos != null){
    Bundle parRecebidos = dadosRecebidos.getExtras();
    if(parRecebidos != null) {
        URL =  parRecebidos.getString("link");
    }
}
```

Porém está vindo nulo o valor. O que está errado?

Comment: tenta trocar de posicao... telaWeb.putExtras(bundleParametro); bundleParametro.putString("link", urlStr);  troca por bundleParametro.putString("link", urlStr); telaWeb.putExtras(bundleParametro);

Comment: Posso sugerir algo que vai funcionar, e diminuir suas linhas de código? poem o valor diretamente no Intent, telaWeb.putExtra("link", urlStr); e na tela 2 pega ele com getIntent().getStringExtra("link")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que em seu código, você está colocando o `Bundle` na `Intent` antes de definir os extras dele:

```
Bundle bundleParametro = new Bundle();
telaWeb.putExtras(bundleParametro);
bundleParametro.putString("link", urlStr);
```

Basta definir seu `Bundle` antes de colocar dentro de sua `Intent`, e em sua outra `Activity`, recupera-lo normalmente:

```
Bundle bundleParametro = new Bundle();
bundleParametro.putString("link", urlStr);
telaWeb.putExtras(bundleParametro);
```

Uma outra maneira de fazer isso, é colocando os extras diretamente na sua `Intent`, por exemplo:

```
Intent telaWeb = new Intent(SegmentoView.this, ViewWeb.class);
telaWeb.putExtras("link", urlStr);
startActivity(telaWeb);
```

E, em sua outra `Activity`:

```
...

if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().hasExtras("link"){
    URL =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não uso o Bundle não. Faça isso pra ver se funciona: `telaWeb.putExtras("link", urlStr)`, e exclua as linhas que usa o objeto **bundleParametro**.